# iCloud implementation for ios 5.1 and 6.0

Tags: ios, core-data, icloud

My newest app uses coredata and I want my users to be able to work on their phone or their ipad, so I have spent the past few days attempting to implement iCloud. Wow, frustrating.  Sometimes the data transfers, sometimes it does not (yet?).  Sometimes the app crashes immediately, sometimes it does not....

All my app needs is to import a small set of data when first installed and synchronize upon loading.

I based my implementation on this model:https://github.com/alekseyn/iCloudStoreManager and made modifications for my needs (such as removing the UI elements added for the example).

I wonder if someone has a simple 5.1 & 6.0 iCloud implementation they would be willing to share?  I am sure there would be a good number of grateful people.

Comment: From the responses here, I can't decide whether to continue with my attempts or not.... ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such thing. iCloud with Core Data is difficult all the way through. The problems you describe are typical, and come not from problems in your app but from problems with Core Data's iCloud integration. By all means, consult sample code, blogs, etc, and maybe you'll improve your app. But you'll still be using iCloud, and you can't fix that.

Answer (score 0):

You can check out these two resources.

http://www.raywenderlich.com/12779/icloud-and-uidocument-beyond-the-basics-part-1

and

https://developer.apple.com/icloud/documentation/

They may be helpful